# Generalized linear mixed effect model for negatively skewed outcome with negative values

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmnet

I have a continuous outcome that is negatively skewed and includes negative, positive, and zero values. There are multiple measurements per subject, and the assumptions of a linear mixed-effects model didn't hold. What's the best family distribution and link function in generalized mixed-effects model that can handle negative and zero values and negative skewness? Is there a better test to use? Can someone help with the code using Stata 17

Here's how my outcome look like
[image]

Comment: Depending on which linear model assumptions are violated, a form of [robust multilevel regression](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustlmm/vignettes/rlmer.pdf) (<-a pdf) could help (sorry, I don't know how to run those in Stata).